# How to write a method subscribing to a topic in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binding?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I want to write a consumer method which subscribes to a topic using KafkaListener.

I found an answer which suggested this -

```
@KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "dead-out")
public void dlq(Message<?> in) {
    System.out.println("DLQ:" + in);
}
```

Now, in the annotation 'topics' is the name of the subscribed topic. But what is 'id' field ? Or is there a better way?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @gary-russell hope you can answer this

Answer (score 2):

`@KafkaListener` has nothing to do with Spring Cloud Stream; it is in the Spring for Apache Kafka project (which Spring Cloud Stream uses for its Kafka binder).

See the javadocs

```java
    /**
     * The unique identifier of the container managing for this endpoint.
     * <p>If none is specified an auto-generated one is provided.
     * <p>Note: When provided, this value will override the group id property
     * in the consumer factory configuration, unless {@link #idIsGroup()}
     * is set to false.
     * <p>SpEL {@code #{...}} and property place holders {@code ${...}} are supported.
     * @return the {@code id} for the container managing for this endpoint.
     * @see org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry#getListenerContainer(String)
     */
    String id() default "";
```

The `id` is also used to get the listener container from the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean so you can `stop()` and `start()` it.

If you want to use spring-cloud-stream instead; read its documentation.

Comment: You can start by using this quick start - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_quick_start. Should take no more then 5 min.